# Remove double quotation mark result from Inline if statement razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to convert this code to one line:

```
@if (Model.Movie == null)
{
    <h2>New Movie</h2>
}
else
{
    <h2>Edit Movie</h2>
}
```

By writing this:

```
<h2>"@(Model.Movie==null?"New Movie": "Edit Movie")"</h2>
```

But the result contains double quotation mark like this `"Edit Movie"` rather than `Edit Movie`. It will fail if I remove the marks from the statement.

How to remove the mark? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the outer quotes. It needs to be just

```
<h2>@(Model.Movie==null?"New Movie": "Edit Movie")</h2>
```